# MySQL how to get number of values from a user?

Tags: mysql

I have this 3 tables:

```
Users:
user_id|user_nick
   1   |    a
   2   |    b

Category:
cat_id|cat_type
   1  |    a
   2  |    b
   3  |    c
   4  |    d

Meta:
met_id|met_name|met_user|met_type
   10 |  bla   |    1   |    1
   11 | blabla |    2   |    2
   12 |  foo   |    1   |    3
   13 | blafoo |    2   |    4
   14 | foofoo |    1   |    4
   15 | foobla |    1   |    4
```

How can I return something like this ?

```
user_id|met_type|total
   1   |   1    |  1
   1   |   2    |  0
   1   |   3    |  1
   1   |   4    |  2
```

For just one user and not for all of them.

met_type is a foreign key from `Category`.

I've tried like this but no success :/

`SELECT met_user, met_type, COUNT(*) FROM Meta GROUP BY met_user WHERE met_user = '1'`

Comment: Yeah, I think `GROUP BY met_user` isn't what you want to do here. The distinct groups are `met_type` with 1, 2, 3, 4, so.

Comment: You should use group_concat function.

Comment: @VijayBarbhaya You should make an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query:

```
SELECT met_user, met_type, count(*)
FROM Meta
WHERE met_user='1'
  GROUP BY met_type;
```

To get empty groups, you can use `generateSeries()` here:

```
SELECT m.met_user, g.meta_type, count(m)
FROM generate_series(1, 4) AS g(meta_type)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Meta AS m
    ON m.met_user='1'
    AND m.met_type=g.meta_type
GROUP BY g.meta_type, m.met_user
ORDER BY g.meta_type;
```

Check it out! I made an [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/df38a/19/0).

Comment: Would you like empty `met_type` groups to show up too?

Comment: Thanks, I never thought about trying to group by `met_type` instead of `met_user`. Must the late hours heheh

Comment: Yes, that would be great if the empty ones showed up :)

Comment: @SnakeSheet Added - I also made an SQL Demo.